# Error in JCache implementation with Hazelcast CompleteConfiguration-class not found

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, jcache

I'm trying to setup a simple example app for testing a jcache implementation of hazelcast. 
Example code:

```
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

Cache<String, String> m = cacheManager.getCache("test");

m.put("key1", "value1");
```

In my pom.xml file both jcache and hazelcast are defined

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-PFD</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the code I get this error. Can't figure out where/how I should define this ComepleteConfiguration class.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/CompleteConfiguration
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider.createHazelcastCacheManager(HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java:71)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider.createHazelcastCacheManager(HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java:42)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager(AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.java:94)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager(AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager(HazelcastCachingProvider.java:156)
    at cacheAdapter.TutorialJCache.initCache(TutorialJCache.java:27)
    at cacheAdapter.TutorialJCache.main(TutorialJCache.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.cache.configuration.CompleteConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong JCache Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
  <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So, use it without PFD which is an older version meant for discussions.